# Reading rows from Google sheets but the returning array is null

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to read data from google sheets and then write cell values to input type text fields. Firefox returns an error "TypeError: conteudo is null" when I try to access an array returning data from GSheets.
[This is the link to my google sheets example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q8kz2L2q4u99dvR0zeDuCghSgtlNKMpbmZgCRHC3hn0/edit?usp=sharing).

Sample data

```
Nome: Name
Data_Nascimento: 20/07/1950
CPF: 12345678
```

See below my code.

File: code.gs

```
function doGet(request) {
    setPage('index');
    return HtmlService
    .createTemplateFromFile('index')
    .evaluate()
    .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
    .setTitle("teste");    
  }
  

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}

var urlss = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q8kz2L2q4u99dvR0zeDuCghSgtlNKMpbmZgCRHC3hn0/edit?usp=sharing";


function setPage(page) {
  var ps=PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  ps.setProperty('PageTitle', page);
  return ps.getProperty('PageTitle');
}


function getConsultaPacientes() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(urlss);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("lista");
  var dadosPaciente = ws.getRange(2,1,ws.getLastRow()-1,3).getValues();
  
  var listaNomePaciente = dadosPaciente.map(function(param) { return param[0];});
  var listaDtNascPaciente = dadosPaciente.map(function(param) { return param[1];});
  var listaCPFPaciente = dadosPaciente.map(function(param) { return param[2];});
 
  pacienteEncontrado = [listaNomePaciente,listaCPFPaciente,listaDtNascPaciente];
  return pacienteEncontrado;
 }
```

File: page_js

```
<script>

document.getElementById("btconsultaPaciente").addEventListener("click",objConsultaPaciente);

function objConsultaPaciente(){
   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(populateDadosPacientes).getConsultaPacientes();
}

function populateDadosPacientes(conteudo) {
   document.getElementById("idnome").value=conteudo[0];
   document.getElementById("idcpf").value=conteudo[1];
   document.getElementById("iddtnascimento").value=conteudo[2];
   M.updateTextFields();
   
   }

</script>
```

File: index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
      <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
      <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
      <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"> -->
    </head>

    <body>
         <div class="container">
  
               <div class="row">        
                  <div class="input-field col s12 m2 l2">
                     <button id="btconsultaPaciente" class="btn tooltipped" data-position="bottom" data-tooltip="Consultar Paciente">Populate</button>               
                  </div>                  
               </div> <!-- CLOSE ROW -->
               
               <div class="divider"></div>
               
               <br>


               <div class="row">        
                  <div class="input-field col s12 m4 l4">
                     <input type="text" id="idnome" class="validate">
                     <label class="active" for="idnome">Nome</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="input-field col s12 m4 l4">
                     <input type="text" id="iddtnascimento" class="datepicker">
                     <label>Data de Nascimento</label>
                  </div>
                  <div class="input-field col s12 m4 l4">
                     <input type="text" id="idcpf" class="validate">
                     <label for="idcpf">CPF</label>
                  </div>                    
               </div> <!-- CLOSE ROW -->
               
 
               <div class="row">
                  <div class="col">
       
                  </div>
               </div> <!-- CLOSE ROW -->                  
          
         </div> <!-- CLOSE CONTAINER --> 
         
      <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
      <?!= include('index_js'); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think that in your script, `getConsultaPacientes` returns `pacienteEncontrado` or `'Indisponível'`. By this, at HTML side, `conteudo` of `populateDadosPacientes(conteudo)` is not `null`. So can I ask you about the method for opening `page_js`? If you want to open it using Web Apps, I would like to propose to redeploy the Web Apps as new version. If you open it using a dialog and sidebar on Google Docs, it might be required to confirm other script related to your current script.

Comment: It's not clear how `populateDadosPacientes` is called. Please add a [mcve].

Comment: @Rubén, I agree with you. I didn't make myself clear. I will edit my post. Thank you.

Comment: @Tanaike, thank you. I will provide more information.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. Sorry. I noticed it just now. So from your updated question, I proposed the modification points as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your situation and goal are as follows.

- There are the values of "Name", "20/07/1950" and "12345678" in the columns "A" to "C" on Google Spreadsheet.

  - "20/07/1950" is the date object.
- You want to put above 3 values to `idnome`, `iddtnascimento` and `idcpf`.
- When the script is run by clicking the button, an error of `TypeError: conteudo is null` occurs.

  - You want to know the reason of this error and remove it.

If my understanding for above situation and goal is correct, I think that your script of Google Apps Script is required to be modified as follows.

#### Modification points:

- If "20/07/1950" is the date object on Spreadsheet, the value of `conteudo` returned by `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(populateDadosPacientes).getConsultaPacientes()` becomes `null`.

  - From your sample values and the error message of `TypeError: conteudo is null`, I thought that this might be the reason of your issue.

When your script is modified, it becomeas as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please modify the function `getConsultaPacientes()` at Google Apps Script side as follows.

From:

```
var dadosPaciente = ws.getRange(2,1,ws.getLastRow()-1,3).getValues();
```

To:

```
var dadosPaciente = ws.getRange(2,1,ws.getLastRow()-1,3).getDisplayValues();
```

or

From:

```
var listaDtNascPaciente = dadosPaciente.map(function(param) { return param[1];});
```

To:

```
var listaDtNascPaciente = dadosPaciente.map(function(param) { return param[1].toISOString()});
```

#### Note:

- If you want to use the value which can be seen at Spreadsheet, the modification using `getDisplayValues()` might be suitable.
- **In your script, Web Apps is used. So when the script of Web Apps is modified, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to it. Please be careful this.**

#### References:

- [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)
- [toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getConsultaPacientes(input) {
  var input=input||10;//default for testing
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();//changed for testing
  var ws=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");//changed sheet name
  var vA=ws.getRange(2,1,ws.getLastRow()-1,13).getValues();
  var list1=vA.map(function(param){return param[12];});
  var list2=vA.map(function(param){return param[0];});
  var list3=vA.map(function(param){return param[1];});
  var pos=list1.indexOf(input);
  if(pos>-1) {
    var pac=[list2[pos],list3[pos]];
    return pac;
  } else {
    return 'Indisponível';
  }
}
```

My Test Data:

```
COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5,COL6,COL7,COL8,COL9,COL10,COL11,COL12,COL13,COL14,COL15
8,2,3,7,3,10,7,11,9,0,9,10,7,4,7
3,0,5,4,1,7,11,10,11,11,0,5,10,5,6
7,10,11,5,8,8,11,6,10,7,6,4,4,2,11
10,0,2,1,7,7,9,9,10,8,5,8,9,8,6
0,10,1,9,0,9,9,0,6,7,9,3,8,11,10
6,6,1,3,5,5,3,4,6,0,5,6,0,0,2
0,11,6,1,7,3,9,1,6,9,4,9,3,9,8
6,7,5,9,11,7,5,9,8,10,11,9,6,2,10
1,4,8,7,7,5,7,9,10,8,5,6,2,7,1
3,5,0,2,1,1,1,1,7,1,11,8,7,11,10
6,3,2,7,2,3,0,5,11,0,8,3,7,11,3
11,6,1,11,2,7,5,10,6,1,11,0,3,3,10
```